# Phalcon ORM showing that the column is ambiguous when traversing model relationships

Tags: mysql, orm, phalcon

I am using Phalcon to query some relations between models.
I have the following models:

```
<?php

class Client extends ModelBase
{
  private $id;
  private $code;
  private $active;

  public function initialize()
  {
    parent::initialize();

    $this->hasManyToMany(
      "id",
      "ClientAddress",
      "client_id",
      "address_id",
      "Address",
      "id",
      array("alias" => "addresses")
    );

  public function getAddresses($params = null) {
    return $this->getRelated("addresses", $params);
  }         
}


class Address extends ModelBase
{
  private $id;
  .......

<?php

class ClientAddress extends ModelBase
{
  private $id;      
  private $active;

  public function initialize()
  {
    parent::initialize();                                              
    $this->belongsTo("client_id", "Client", "id", array(
      "alias" => "client"
    ));

    $this->belongsTo("address_id", "Address", "id", array(
      "alias" => "address"
    ));
  }
}
```

I am receiving the below error:

`The column 'id' is ambiguous, when preparing: SELECT [Address].* FROM [Address] INNER JOIN [ClientAddress] ON [ClientAddress].[address_id] = [Address].[id] WHERE [ClientAddress].[client_id] = ?0 AND id = ?1`

The code that generates this error is:

```
$client = Client::findFirst(array(
    "conditions" => "id = ?1",
    "bind" => array( 1 => $current_client_id )
  ));

  $addresses = $client->getAddresses(array(
    "conditions" => "id = ?1",
    "bind" => array( 1 => $id )
  ));
```

Why is this happening? Do I not have my relations setup properly? I would have assumed that it would prefix my where clause with the table name?

Comment: Do the models work correctly when using a different clause or no clause?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem than you. I fixed it by adding

```
$client = Client::findFirst(array(
    "conditions" => "[ClientAddress].[id] = ?1",
    "bind" => array( 1 => $current_client_id )
  ));

  $addresses = $client->getAddresses(array(
    "conditions" => "[Address].[id] = ?1",
    "bind" => array( 1 => $id )
  ));
```

You have the following problem when you have the same column name of two different MySQL table

Comment: Thanks.. I think that's what I ended up doing, of may have just written it in PHQL. Quite a silly bug really, having an id column in multiple tables is always going to happen.

Comment: A problem is that you can't set an alias for the 'FROM' table and when you are using namespaces then it starts to look weird.